# How can I use an external python module with SQL 2017 sp_execute_external_script?

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm testing out the SQL 2017 machine learning services that allow you to run python scripts in a stored procedure.  I see plenty of examples of how to run a python script when the script is defined in the stored procedure itself, but I'd like to know how to import my own python modules.  Something like this:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
from test import sample
x = sample.SomeClass()
x.SomeFunction()
'
```

Is this possible?  Is there another method for my to run my own python scripts in SQL?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188907/sql-server-2017-external-python-modules

Comment: @MitchWheat, as far as I can tell this will only let me import a public module which I've installed to the server.  I'm not sure if this method will allow me to import a private module I've written myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you may do this by extending the sys.path environment variables by the adding the location of `test` module in your code like this

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import sys
sys.path += ['D:\\path_to_your_test_module']
from test import sample as sa
x = sa.SomeClass()
x.SomeFunction()
'
```

Comment: Great stuff, wish you were there when I needed you months ago!  Joking aside, thank you.  Hopefully this helps somebody else.