# sp_execute_external_script can't find modules installed by setuptools

Tags: python, sql-server, setuptools, egg

I am actively developing a Python module that I would like to deploy in SQL Server 2017 installed locally, so I deploy the module in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<Instance Name>\PYTHON_SERVICES\Lib\site-packages`using `setuptools`like so:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<Instance_Name>\PYTHON_SERVICES\python" setup.py develop
```

This produces an `.egg-info` directory in my project root, and a `.egg-link` file in the `site-packages` directory mentioned above. The `.egg-link` file correctly points to the `.egg-info` directory in my project root, so it appears `setuptools` is working correctly.

Here's my `setup.py`for reference:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    pbr=True,
)
```

And here's the corresponding `setup.cfg` file:

```
[metadata]
name = <module_name>
description = <Module Description>
description-file = README.md
description-content-type = text/markdown

[files]
package_root = py/src
```

Since I am just trying to make the plumbing work, I have a single python script called `uploader.py` in `<project_root>/py/src`:

```
#uploader.py
class Upload:
    pass
```

With this deployment in place, I am hoping to simply `import` the module I just published through `.egg-link` into a `sp_execute_external_script` call like so:

```
execute sp_execute_external_script @language= N'Python', @script= N'from <module_name>.uploader import Upload';
```

However, executing this stored procedure from SSMS produces the following error message:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 10
A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
An external script error occurred: 

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\SQL-MSSQLSERVER-ExtensibilityData-PY\MSSQLSERVER01\C08BB9A7-66B5-4B5E-AAFC-B0248EE64199\sqlindb.py", line 27, in transform
    from <module_name>.uploader import Upload
ImportError: No module named '<module_name>'

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<Instance_Name>\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 587, in rx_sql_satellite_call
    rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<Instance_Name>\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 358, in rx_native_call
    ret = px_call(functionname, params)
RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.
```

I have obviously redacted `module_name` and `Instance_Name` from the error message.

I tried using `install` command instead of `develop` just to make sure the `.egg-link` file is not a problem. `install` installs the `.egg-info` file in `site-packages` but I get the same error.

I also tried removing `pbr` from the mix, but got the same error.

Lastly, I tried adding my `<project_root>` to `sys.path` as suggested by [How can I use an external python module with SQL 2017 sp_execute_external_script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982439/how-can-i-use-an-external-python-module-with-sql-2017-sp-execute-external-script), but that didn't help either.

So at this point, I don't have a clue what I might be doing wrong.

The python version is `3.5.2` and I don't think an `__init__.py` is needed in the project for it to qualify as a module. Inserting a blank `__init__.py` in `py/src` doesn't help either.

My `pip` version is `19.3.1` and `setuptools` version is `44.0.0` and `pbr` version is `5.4.4` and I have confirmed all modules are installed in the `site-packages` directory mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my extensive experimentation, it appears that `sp_execute_external_script` doesn't follow symlinks (i.e. through the`.egg-link` file). Therefore, development mode installations will not work, whether you use `setuptools`, `pip`, `pbr` or anything else.

I even tried symlinking `<package_name>` folder as an OS symlink. Since I am on Windows, I used `mklink /D` command on Command Prompt to symlink `/py/src/<package_name>` inside `site-packages`. While the command goes through correctly, and I can see the symlinked folder in File Explorer, `sp_execute_external_script` fails to detect the package. Which tells me that there is probably something in `sp_execute_external_script` code that avoids traversing symbolic links.

I wonder if there is a way to make it traverse symbolic links.

The only workable solution is to develop a package's code under its own directory, so, in my case `/py/src/<package_name>`. Then, before running `exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'python', @script=N'...'` copy the `<package_name>` folder to the `site-packages` directory.

This is, sort of, equivalent to `setup.py install`, but bypasses the creation of intermediate files and directories. So I am going to stick with this simple--though odious--approach.

I am hoping somebody more knowledgeable would offer a better way to solve this problem.